# How to change colors of individual characters in a header

Tags: javascript

My object is to take a header and by only using JavaScript (no JQuery), randomly color each individual letter. What I have seems to be pretty close:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="demo">TEST</h1>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
  var x=document.getElementById("demo");
  var l=x.innerHTML.length;
  var newText="";
  for(var a=0;a<l;a++)
  {
    var letter = x.innerHTML.charAt(a);
    newText += letter.fontcolor(getColor());
  }
  x.innerHTML=newText;
  alert(x.innerHTML);
}

function getColor()
{
  var colorString="";
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*17);
    hexNum = num.toString(16);
    colorString += hexNum;
  }
  return colorString;
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What's happening is the fontcolor method actually does `<FONT color=#FF0000>T</FONT><FONT color=#00FF00>E</FONT><FONT color=#0000ff>S</FONT><FONT color=#000000>T</FONT>` This works for the first time I hit the button, but the next time I hit it, it does the fontcolor for every letter in the code snipit. I've confirmed this based on my alert I have in my code. Is there a more practical way of coloring individual letters? Is it possible to retrieve just the letters from the header instead of the letters plus the font coloring code? I'm unable to use JQuery and, if possible, would rather not use spans. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how with vanilla JS but in jQuery you can get the string using `.text()` which will omit the HTML tags.

Comment: In order to style each letter, you will have to wrap it in something.  A `span` is the best fit, given what you're trying to accomplish.  `font` is deprecated and you should be phasing it out and not adding it to new code.

Comment: If you do decide to use jQuery, check out [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after calling the function once `x.innerHTML` will not only contain the text, but also the HTML for the `font` elements. If you want to get the inner text only, you can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) or `innerText` (depending on the browser):

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var text = x.textContent || x.innerText;
var newText="";
for(var a=0; a < text.length; a++) {
    var letter = text.charAt(a);
    // ...
}
```

---

If you don't care about IE8 or IE7, you can do this more elegantly with:

```
var new_text = Array.prototype.map.call(x.textContent || x.innerText, function(letter) {
    return letter.fontcolor(getColor());
}).join('');
```

But you really shouldn't use the font element anymore, it's deprecated since ages.

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks for the warning of it being deprecated. I came across that during my research, but I just wanted to get something to work. This was just a little exercise for me. Extra thanks for the better alternative!

Comment: What if it is a text of Arabic or some other languages like the word. دبئی?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: [`fontcolor` is not standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor) and `<font>` elements are deprecated!

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

You can use `.textContent`:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("demo"),
        txt = x.textContent,
        newText = "";
    for(var i=0, l=txt.length; i<l; i++)
    {
        newText += txt.charAt(i).fontcolor(getColor());
    }
    x.innerHTML = newText;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ky85J/)

Comment: I appreciate your warning. I'll be sure to remember that if I ever do anything similar to this in production. This was just a sample task for me to get the hang of entry-level JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("demo"),
        txt = x.innerHTML;
    (myFunction = function() {
        var newText = "";
        for(var i=0, l=txt.length; i<l; i++)
        {
            newText += '<span style="color:#'+getColor()+'">'+txt.charAt(i)+'</span>';
        }
        x.innerHTML = newText;
    })();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ky85J/1/)

It works on old browsers because it doesn't use `.textContent`, and doesn't use the non-standard `fontcolor`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could before you replace the text, you move the text in the title attribute, and then use the attribute for the original text and then you will always have the original text.  For example:

```
<h1>Flip That</h1>
```

Then you have your script before it does the random colors set the title if it hasn't been set before like below:

```
<h1 title="Flip That">Flip That</h1>
```

Then you always use the title instead for the original string:

```
<h1 title="Flip That"><font color="#0a0a0a">F</font><font color="#0b0b0b">l</font><font color="#0c0c0c">i</font><font color="#0d0d0d">p</font><font color="#0e0e0e"> </font><font color="#0a0a0a">T</font><font color="#0b0b0b">h</font><font color="#0b0b0b">a</font><font color="#0b0b0b">t</font></h1>
```